# CSS footer margin problems

Tags: css, margin

I've got a page which is laid out like this:

```
<div class="report">
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Lots of irrelevant stuff -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <!-- Footer content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My footer is supposed to extend to the extreme left of the screen, but my 'report' class has a .25in left margin applied.

I've tried using a -.25in left margin, but this does not pull my footer left as expected.  It doesn't seem to be moving the footer at all, in fact.

I know my CSS is tragetted correctly, because I can affect other attributes (top, bottom margin, color, etc) but I cannot get the footer to extend to the far left of the screen.

Unfortunately, I can't simply pull the footer outside of the 'report' div.

CSS:

```
.report
{
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-left: 0.25in;
    width: 775px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 -0.25in;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Please show your css?

Comment: @BillyMathews: CSS added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get your footer outside of your parent `<div>` because of the `overflow: hidden;` on your `.report`. Try to remove it, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qbgp2/).

Answer (score 2):

As it's the footer, you could try `position: relative; left: -.25in;`. BTW, why are you using inches?

Comment: We are using inches because the page I'm working with is converted to a PDF for the user to download or print.

Comment: Also, sadly, that CSS is exactly what I started out trying to use :(

Comment: Ach, sorry - was worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

**[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CgWB2/3/)** works for me

The `overflow: hidden` on your `.report` element was hiding the footer, but it was in the right place.

Comment: Oddly, your fiddle puts the 'footer' above the content (or possibly extends the report beyond the footer).  Either way, it looks odd. :)

Comment: I gave the main div a declared, fixed height, so that you can see it; and there is no content in the main div, so the footer flows up. http://jsfiddle.net/CgWB2/3/